# How to get multiple rows united by common column in mysql in complex select with join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, internationalization, translation

I have 2 tables, one holding pages, the other holding translated values for some of the pages properties:

**pages**
-id,in_menu,created_at ... etc

**page_translations**
- id,page_id,locale, title,content... etc 
(row for each locale)

I need to create a table with 2 locales - re joining the translation

#### pages

```
--- id --- title_en ---- title_he --- in_menu
    1     someTitle     Translated    true
```

I am using laravel (4.1) 
so what i did is:

```
Page:join('page_translations', 'pages.id', '=', 'page_translations.page_id')
->select(array('pages.id', 'page_translations.page_id as 
  pageId','page_translations.title as title_en', 'page_translations.title as 
  title_he','pages.in_menu', 'pages.created_at'))
->where('page_translations.locale','=','en')
->groupBy('page_translations.page_id');
```

the result sql (for ones that don't dig laravel)

```
select `pages`.`id`, `page_translations`.`page_id` as `pageId`,
`page_translations`.`title` as `title_en`, `page_translations`.`title` as `title_he`,
```

`pages`.`in_menu`, `pages`.`created_at` from `pages` inner join `page_translations` on
   `pages`.`id` = `page_translations`.`page_id` where `page_translations`.`locale` = 'en'
    group by `page_translations`.`page_id`

now I have the title twice (as title_en and title_he) and so I used another query to replace the title_he with the right value

```
PageTranslation::wherePageId($pageId)->whereLocale('he')->pluck('title')
```

I want to know if anyone can make it in a single query call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the page_translations table twice:

```
Page:join('page_translations AS page_translations_en', function($join) {
    $join->on('pages.id', '=', 'page_translations_en.page_id'),
    $join->on('page_translations_en.locale', '=', 'en')
})->join('page_translations AS page_translations_he', function($join) {
    $join->on('pages.id', '=', 'page_translations_he.page_id'),
    $join->on('page_translations_he.locale', '=', 'he')
})
->select(array('pages.id AS page_id', 'page_translations_en.title as title_en', 'page_translations_he.title as 
  title_he','pages.in_menu', 'pages.created_at'))
->groupBy('page_translations.page_id');
```

Can't guarantee that will work out-of-the-box as I don't have a copy of your schema, but you get the idea.